# Different environments included in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, test-environments, environments

Can someone explain to me what the Rails environments are and what they do? I have tried researching myself, but could not find anything. From what I gather, the environments are:

- Development
- Productions
- Test

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's not very clear what you are asking, here. Although you might find some answers in the rails configuration guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Check this also a better explanation  http://teotti.com/use-of-rails-environments/

Comment: @apark Do you need additional explanation, still, on the different environments?

Comment: If you could yes please

Answer (score 3):

From what you have provided in your question, it seems that you are asking:

***"What are the difference between each environment configuration in Rails?"***

Rails comes packages with 3 types of environments. Each have its own server, database, and configuration. See [Rails Guides: Configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) for more information on options available to you.

## Setting up the environment

To set your Rails environment, you will want to enter in command line:

```
export RAILS_ENV=<env>
```

Where `<env>` can be `test`, `development`, or `production`. Setting this environment variable is crucial, as it will determine what gems are installed, or what env is touched when running `rails console` or `rails server`.

Included in configuration is the gemset used for the app. When you run `rails new`, you will find a Gemfile with groups `test`, `development`, and `production`. These groups correspond to the environment currently set. When the environment is set to one of those, running `bundle install` installs all gems related to that group (and gems not listed in a group).

## Included environments

**`test`** is designed for running tests/specs. This database will likely be bare bones, except for seeds you may call before running the suite. After each test is complete, the database will rollback to its state before the test began. I do not recommend launching `rails server`, as running tests (via MiniTest or RSpec) will do this for you, and close the server once the suite is finished.

**`development`** allows you to "test" your app with a larger database, typically a clone of production. This allows you to test *actual* real-world data without breaking production (the version that customers or end-users will experience). To view the development environment in action, change the `RAILS_ENV` and launch `rails server`. This is good for deciding how you want your pages to look (CSS, HTML). It is also good practice to briefly "test" your app yourself, clicking around making sure everything "looks" good and the JavaScript works.

**`production`** is reserved for the customer and end-user. Configuration includes the actual domain of the app, which ports to use, and initializers or tasks to run. You do not want to play around with your database, as it may be customer-impacting. Ideally, the app should work as best as it can, since this is considered your "final product."

Answer (score 2):

Each "environment" is really just a config.  You can launch your app in various different modes, and the modes are called "environments" because they affect the app's behaviour in lots of different ways.  Ultimately, though, they are just configs.

BTW you can't have looked very hard when you looked "everywhere", because i just googled "rails environment" and the top result was this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

which is the official explanation of configuring the rails environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good reads about Rails Environments

http://teotti.com/use-of-rails-environments/

and

https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments

good luck !!